# React returning null on window.location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth

I'm trying to use discord.js oauth, and for that I need to be able to get the oauthpage.location.hash, but when I try to log oauthpage.location, it returns an empty location object: `Location {ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, href: 'about:blank', origin: 'null', protocol: 'about:', host: '', …}`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
const oauthpage = window.open(url, "_blank", "height=1000,width=500")
console.log(oauthpage?.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open() returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#implicit-grant-flow - See `window.onload`